# Gravity from thermodynamics - current state of this program?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity

I heard of papers that apparently derived Einstein field equations (EFE) from law of thermodynamics. How valid is the claim that EFE can be derived from thermodynamics, and if it is valid, is EFE derived as emergent macroscopic theory or emergent microscopic theory?

Comment: Citations of the papers would be a good thing to add.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0785

Comment: The derivations are certainly valid in that they correctly predict $G_{\mu\nu}=T_{\mu\nu}$. Whether or not it is ultimately correct to associate the particle flux across a horizon with a heat flow, surface gravity with a temperature, etc. is controversial (and I think people are pretty entrenched in their opinions). One very appealing aspect of thermodynamic gravity is you get around the problem of having to quantize gravity since GR is not the correct theory on microscopic scales.